# nomethoderror rails layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, nomethoderror

I'm new to rails and trying to make a link in my header to sign in/out of a profile. I'm not  the issue with the following code, specifically the bolded (**) area:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="brand"> Test App</a>
            <ul class="nav">
        <li><%= link_to "All Statuses", statuses_path %></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        **<li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, "#" %></li>**

      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
   <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

I keep getting an error that says:

NoMethodError in Statuses#index

Showing /Users/test_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #18):

```
 <li><%= link_to "All Statuses", statuses_path %></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, "#" %></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

The status controller code is:

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
 # GET /statuses
 # GET /statuses.json
  def index

@statuses = Status.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @statuses }
end
   end

# GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/new
  # GET /statuses/new.json
  def new
    @status = Status.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @status }
    end
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = Status.new(params[:status])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /statuses/1
  # PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update_attributes(params[:status])
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @status.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show the EXACT error text and also the controller code for the index method in the Status controller.

Comment: I have updated with the status controller and error text. Thanks @MichaelDurrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you calling `current_user.full_name`, but `current_user` is `nil` and method can not be called on it.
What you can do is following:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <% if current_user %>
    <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, "#" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This will display your link only when user is logged in(it means that `current_user` will return user instance, instead of `nil`)